# Passing a .php file as a parameter

Tags: php

Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way, but I have a Configuration file that I'm trying to pass through a parameter, the reason I'm doing this is because I'm experimenting with what I call a ("Core"/"Client") structure, probably not the correct name, but basically whatever I edit on the "Core" is updated to all of the "Client" subdomains, which will respectively call code such as

```
include '/path/to/core/index.php';
generateIndex($Param, $Param);
```

So, Basically, here's what I have, on the "Clients" side I have a Configuration file, called "**Configuration.php**" this holds all of the static variables pertaining to the Clients database. Example below:

```
<?php
    $SQL_HOST = "";
    $SQL_DATBASE = "";
    $SQL_ACCOUNT_TABLE = "";
    $SQL_DATA_TABLE = "";
    $SQL_REWARDS_TABLE = ""; 
    $SQL_USERNAME = "";
    $SQL_PASSWORD = "";
?>
```

So, Basically, I'm trying to do this,

```
generateIndex($SQLConnection, $Configuration);
```

However, It's not allowing me to do so and presenting me with this error.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: Configuration in /opt/lampp/htdocs/client/index.php on line 16
```

Respectively, Line 16 is the line above containing "generateIndex"

Now, on the "Core" side what I'm trying to do is the following to get data.

```
function generateIndex($SQLConnection, $SQLConfig) {
    ...
        $SQLConfig->TBL_NAME
    ...
}
```

Which I don't know if it throws an error yet, because I can't pass $Configuation to the function.

Comment: It seems you need to define your $Configuration variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can user return context for get variable from file.

As example:

File `db_config.php`:

```
<?php 
return array(
  'NAME' => 'foo_bar',
  'USER' => 'qwerty',
  'PASS' => '12345',
  // Any parameters
);
```

You another file with include configuration:

```
<?php
// Code here...
$dbConfig = include 'db_config';
// Code here
```

If file have a return statement, then your can get this values with `=` operator and include file.

Comment: How would I go about connecting to a database with this method? 
Currently I use -- -require_once 'Configuration.php';
 try {
  $SQLConnection = new PDO('mysql:host' .$SQL_HOST. ';dbname='.$SQL_DATBASE, $SQL_USERNAME, $SQL_PASSWORD);

Comment: Try: `$config = include 'file_config.php'; $SQLConnection = new PDO("...{$config['NAME']}...{$config['USER']}....")`

Comment: Thank you. Last question, do you happen to know a name for the "Core/Client" structure I'm talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Read the file before putting it in the function.

```
generateIndex($SQLConnection, file("configuration.php"));
```

Answer (score 0):

file 1:
function test() {
   global $Configuration;

echo $Configuration
}

file 2 (perhaps config)
$Configuration = "Hi!";

Comment: The function for generateIndex is in a different directory than the class calling it. Also, there will be multiple "Configuration.php" files. So it's not just calling one.